# Why are events created with timezone-less dates showing the wrong time on facebook.com?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, timezone

For example, take this event:

210489449014070 [Facebook Event](https://www.facebook.com/events/210489449014070/) / [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=210489449014070)

This event was created back in September 2011.  When it was created, it correctly showed Friday, November 11, 2011 11:11pm as the date and time of the event.

But now, it shows Saturday, November 12, 2011 12:11am as the date.  This is also happening for future events, such as 426044564103401.

However, it's not happening for even e.g. in the current month like 330237680381087.

Which show the correct date (same as graph shows.)  This one was created a few months ago.

My suspicion is that it's still applying the DST offset to the date.  For example, right now, pacific time is 7 hours from UTC (because DST is in effect, thus PDT.)  On 2012-11-04, DST will end and it will go back to 8 hours from UTC.  It "falls back" in fall.

The date on the frontend of Facebook.com is showing as if it's still using the 7 hour offset (it's an hour ahead of what it should be.)  My assumption/guess is that at 2012-11-04 02:00:00, it will begin showing the correct date.  Hurray?  But at that point, the dates that are correct now will probably show wrong (because it won't apply DST anymore.)

I'm guessing this means that internally, timezone-less events are now treated as "-07:00" or "-08:00" globally, based on the current UTC offset, rather than a date-relative one.

Do I have to pull all 186,272 events and update all of them to use timezone dates to fix this (also impacting frontend display to other users, and possibly impacting other parties that are interfacing with these events via FQL or etc.)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Graph API explorer says 11:11pm when I query it: `"name": "Wale \"Ambition Tour\" plus Black Cobain plus Brenton Duvall (DJ Set)", 
  "description": "This event was created by Concert Calendar...", 
  "start_time": "2011-11-11T23:11:00",`.  When I try to view the event on FB, the event info is blank (no start time displayed), which is strange.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a bug with displaying the event time and DST.  I was also able to find this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298439903596346

Answer (score 0):

Was probably an issue when Facebook as migrating towards timezone-less events http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/